# jQuery and onclick html function callback

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Let's say we have like 3 functions:

```
// Notice there are no $(document).ready function
function third(par)
{
    // uses jQuery.fadeIn() and jQuery.fadeOut()
}

function second()
{
    // do normal javascript
    third('Something')
}

function main()
{
   var response = $.ajax() // an ajax call with jQuery
}
```

Now let's take a look at an HTML page

```
<button onclick="main()">Click me, please</button>
```

It seems that functions define inside `$(document).ready` are unavailable out side, so `main()` will be undefined if putted inside `$(document).ready`
I've checked the actions of each function with FireBug and i can tell you this:

- The `main()` function is called and the ajax call called returning the right data.
- The `second()` function is called successfully
- The `third()` function is called but an error occur: fadeIn() is not defined as any other jQuery functions.

My question is: what should i do to attach a jQuery function to an HTML onclick event caller?

Comment: Since you're using jQuery anyway, you should use the jQuery ways of attaching event handlers to DOM elements and stop using "onclick" etc.

Comment: why don't use http://api.jquery.com/click/ ?

Comment: Which functions are defined inside `$(document).ready`? Why would one define them inside there in the first place? Where is `second` called?

Comment: @Pointly, because the live or click jQuery functions need of a class or an id that listen to the event. In this way that would be pretty bad in my case since my HTML is already messed up by itsown. Also it seems to me that onclick events are way more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$`('button').click(main);` inside document ready

or

```
var main;

$(document).ready(function(){
main = function(){...}
...
});
```